# css and scss in twig file

Tags: css, symfony, sass, assetic

I want to include a .css and .scss file in a twig template, is it necessary to write is this way?

```
{% stylesheets filter="sass"
    "css/proposal/edit.scss"
    "bundles/bmatznerfontawesome/scss/font-awesome.scss"
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}

{% stylesheets
    "bundles/simplemde/debug/simplemde.css"
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

I dont like the redundant writing, but when I try to link the css file in the first block that is filtered for scss files it wont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the filter attribute and add an 'apply_to' option in your config :

```
// app/config.yml :

assetic:
    # ...
    filters:
        sass:
            # ...
            apply_to: ".scss$"
```

Then you can group everything in the first :

```
{% stylesheets 
    "css/proposal/edit.scss"
    "bundles/bmatznerfontawesome/scss/font-awesome.scss"
    "bundles/simplemde/debug/simplemde.css"
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```